# Serving static files in Express dese not work

Tags: node.js

I have a folder named `public` in  the root of my project . I would like to put all my images/css in that.

Now, I want to put the serving static section in the separate module named config:

```
//config.js

const express = require('express');  
module.exports = function (app) {
   app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
}
```

then in the `server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

require('./startup/config')(app);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Hi, How's it going ?")
})

app.listen(4500, () => {
    console.log("Server is running ...");
})
```

Now, when I want to call the following address

```
http://localhost:4500/static/xxx.jpg
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot GET /static/xxx.jpg
```

Structure Of Project :

```
-node_modules
-server.js
-public
-------xxx.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `config.js` file is located in `/startup` directory.
`__dirname` refers to the directory where the current file located.

So you are trying to serve from `./startup/public` instead of `./public`

You could try to use `process.cwd()` instead of `__dirname` in your `config.js` file